# How to add new task below the currently selected task

Tags: ms-project

When adding steps/tasks to a project plan, I often do this sequentially in the order they need to be done.

However, pressing "Insert" adds the new task *above* the current task. How can I add new tasks *below* the currently selected task?

(Bonus question: Why is inserting *above* the default?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I add new tasks below the currently selected task?

You cannot. The [Microsoft page for Adding New Tasks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-new-tasks-6990803e-d0c7-48aa-94c9-ef14387f6792) starts by saying "*Select the row **below** where you want a new task to appear.*"

All other Google results give the same impression: it's simply not possible to add new tasks below the currently selected task.

> Why is inserting above the default?

That's because you can always add tasks below the last line, since there are *blank* lines, but how do you add above the top line?

So Microsoft decided that *Insert* and *Add Above the Top Task* will use the same code and thus save them coding, debugging and adding the above/below option to each "add a task" operation.

That's a good Project Management decision; if you ignore the dubious User Experience. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two Use Cases

1. You want to enter a new task in the middle of a task list at the correct level of indentation: Select the task you want to insert below -> [Enter] -> [Enter] -> [Insert]. This will insert the task below the task selected
2. You just entered a task in the middle of the list: [Enter] -> [Insert]. This will insert the task below the original task